# Spring Security authentication pop up keeps popping

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm having trouble with the spring security

I'm doing it with materialize and angularjs

so here's the problem

See first pic, no error is shown
[image: Landing page]

Second pic when I entered invalid credentials
(username and password should be : asd)
[image: Failed]

Third pic is when I clicked cancel
[image: Failedagain]

Fourth pic is when I entered the correct credentials
[image: Success]

Spring keeps popping when invalid credential is entered, I already tried
.httpBasic().disable but when I do this I can't even login after I enter correct credentials

what to do? :(

EDITED:
[image]
As requested

Comment: check if you do not send any request that needs to be authorized, this pop ups when server returns 401 code (Unauthorized)

Comment: well if the credential is invalid it pops